# Proper way to add the same printer twice with the same default settings: Evince doesn't respect those settings

Tags: cups, evince

I want to add the same printer multiple times with different names and different settings. For example one time with color the other time with black white.

I did this using the default printer dialogue in lubuntu (ldxe) and configured there one printer to use color as default setting and the other one black and white. I also checked the settings in the cups web interface.

Say now I print something in black and white in evince the setting of the color printer changes also to black and white, i.e. if I  print something the next time in evince (even after restarting evince) with the color printer it prints out in black and white. The same problem the other way around.

Firefox seems to respect the printer settings as well as libreoffice and okular.

Comment: sounds like a bug.  try submitting a bug report to gnome.  search their bug tracker first in case anyone else has reported the same bug.

Comment: Can you post the pertinent conf file?